# Velocity template and java code inside

Tags: java, templates, velocity

it's possible to use java code in velocity template ? 
for example use this int template:

```
double x = minutes/60 + (((minutes % 60)<=15)?0.0:((minutes % 60)<=45)?0.5:1.0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Velocity is just a simple templating engine which prints anything that's not valid Velocity syntax.

But it does support computations, although with a much a simpler set of operations. This works in Velocity:

```
#set ($x = $minutes / 60)
#if ($minutes % 60 <= 15)
  #set ($x = $x + 0.0)
#elseif ($minutes % 60 <= 45)
  #set ($x = $x + 0.5)
#else
  #set ($x = $x + 1.0)
#end
```

Comment: OK, but I can't use '%' in Velocity template ?
Anyway I get error, and there is problem with double value, how to pass ?

Lexical error at line 169, column 51.  Encountered: "0" (48), after : "."

Comment: It does support `%`. At least in modern versions. Are you perhaps using Velocity 1.4 or lower?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu no chance to instantiate an object inside the template, right? Something like `#set ($myObj = new Object())`. If not, I imagine that one possibility would be to put into the template's context an object that instantiates another objects.

Comment: @MatheusSantana Indeed, there is no `new` in Velocity, but you can place a factory object in the context.